# When testing my c++ code in Xcode, using "Ab cde Fg" as a test string, my code returns "Not Unique"...Why? The code is listed below

Tags: c++, xcode, unique, getline

I have been practicing interview questions in C++ in Xcode, however I have come across unexpected behavior, yet no compilation error. The code is expected to return whether or not a string contains all unique ASCII characters or not. Testing my code in Xcode on my Mac, with the string "Ab cde Fg" returns "Not Unique". Why is this?

```
bool isUnique1(std::string str)
{
    if (str.length() > 128)
        return false;

    bool * barr = new bool[128];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        int val = str[i];

        if (barr[val])
            return false;

        barr[val] = true;
    }

    delete[] barr;
    return true;

}

int main()
{

    std::string name;
    bool result1;

    std::cout << "Enter a string to test: ";
    getline (std::cin, name);

    result1 = isUnique1(name);

    if (result1)
        std::cout << "Unique \n";
    else
        std::cout << "Not Unique \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The array is not initialized. Write

```
bool * barr = new bool[128]();
```

Pay attention to that this string

```
"Ab cde Fg"
   ^   ^
```

contains non-unique spaces.

Maybe you should write the function such a way that it would ignore white spaces.

If to ignore white spaces then the function can be defined for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <cctype>

bool isUnique1( const std::string &s )
{
    std::set<char> set;
    std::pair<std::set<char>::iterator, bool> p( std::set<char>::iterator(), true );

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; p.second && i < s.size(); i++ )
    {
        if ( not std::isspace( ( unsigned char )s[i] ) ) p = set.insert( s[i] );
    }

    return p.second;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isUnique1( "Ab cde Fg" ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
```

Otherwise if white spaces must not be ignored then the loop will look like

```
for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; p.second && i < s.size(); i++ )
{
    p = set.insert( s[i] );
}
```

Or without a loop the function can be written the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

bool isUnique1( const std::string &s )
{
    return std::set<char>( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ) ).size() == s.size();
}

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isUnique1( s ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I had been so blind with frustration looking right past double space character as well.